# Any link(http/https) identified as "mailto" and open a New Email in Browser

Tags: google-chrome, email, url, links

We have a windows application that has links to various sites. But regardless of the link the user clicks, New Google Mail pops up in Chrome ? 
This issue happens in just one machine after the user upgraded to windows 7.
What could be the issue ? Thanks in Advance.

Wrong URL from Browser
https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=http://abcsharepointent/Ecom/OnlineHelp/OMS/Wiki%20Pages/note%20maintenance.aspx

Correct URL from Browser (in other machines)
http://abcsharepointent/Ecom/OnlineHelp/OMS/Wiki%20Pages/note%20maintenance.aspx

What could be the reason.

Chrome settings were reset to default. But the issue persist.

I tried both "http and https" in Run. Issue persists for both. The command against both seems fine too when I compared it to another system which works fine

Comment: Does this problem also persist when using the `https` protocol? Try this by executing `http://www.google.com` and `https://www.google.com` in Run (Windows + R). In thas case, could you check the Windows Register for the `http` key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http` and compare it to the `https` key.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried both "http and https" in Run. Issue persists for both. The command against both seems fine too when I compared it to another system which works fine